# How to determine if a mobile browser is meta-refresh capable?

Tags: http, browser, redirect, mobile

Many browsers in Japan (EZWeb, i-mode, etc) don't allow meta refresh, and in fact, they may display warning messages such as "This page uses newer technology and cannot be displayed" in place of your webpage.

How can I tell if a mobile browser does not support meta-refreshing so that I can take different action in those cases?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need meta-refresh?  There are many other methods of achieving this.  Most mobile browsers run JavaScript actually.

Comment: @Brad thanks for your comment. I want to use meta-refresh because, no, most mobile browsers (smartphones excluded here), in Japan at least, do NOT support javaScript. I know because I am there and test on multiple handsets (EZweb, i-mode).

Comment: Alright then, why do you want a refresh?  Is it for a simple redirect?  If so, you can do an HTTP 304 with the `Location:` header and any device supporting HTTP should follow it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option for something like this is to display a link on the page with the meta-refresh.  The traditional "click here if the page doesn't redirect you in 5 seconds" kind of thing.  That's what has been done for years in the PC realm.

You should also consider an HTTP 304 with the `Location:` header if you are just redirecting.

If instead you want a page to reload after a specific amount of time, then you are stuck.  Without JavaScript, there is no other method you can use to automatically do this.

Answer (score 0):

Without JavaScript you're really limited to User Agent sniffing.  To provide the best experience I would recommend use known UA strings to only send the meta-refresh to browsers you know can handle it and for those that you don't know send a plain HTML response that has a link for users to click on to do the refresh.